# Blockfrost API and IPFS issues

Tags: nft, api, blockfrost

Right now I have some NFTs to pin on the blockfrost IPFS. That way I don't need to run the node 24h a day. But for some reason the API returns an error when I try to add new assets.

I'm using a free account and have used 0/100mb so far. I used that before and it worked but now it doesn't anymore.

This is the endpoint I'm using:

```
curl "https://ipfs.blockfrost.io/api/v0/ipfs/add" \
  -X POST \
  -H "project_id: $PROJECT_ID" \
  -F "file=@./README.md"
```

The file I want to upload is a zip with a few KB, so not a big thing.

The error is an invalid project key, support says I need an IPFS key but I don't know how to obtain that.

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts hi, this is basically a forbidden 403 error. I dont know why because I'm using my correct api. support says I must use a ipfs key but I dont know how to generate those...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is strange but blockfrost doesnt have the same api key for cardano mainnet and the ipfs.
You must create another project in order to use their api.
that's it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - each network is a different API endpoint. Cardano maininet, Cardano testnet, IPFS, Cardano Alonzo...